# Android Firestore search collection where document is Unique id

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible with Firestore to retrieve the data within a document where the name of the document is unknown or a unique id. Like in the linked image. The ID is unknown whereas the name is known, is it possible to get the ID in this instance?
[image: Database structure example]

```
db.collection("users").document(??).collection("John Doe");
```

Comment: You mean you want to go to a `John Doe` collection whereever it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will nee a name query :

```
var peopleRef = db.collection("users");
// there may multiple users if there are more then one `John Doe`
peopleRef.where("name", "==", "John Doe")
.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        //Here below will list all people who's name = "John Doe", If only one then this John Doe's  id no: doc.id as fallow:
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

Comment: if we used "where" condition it will stop real time update in recycle view???

Answer (score 1):

Thank's to HakanC's answer I modified it a little to get it working as shown below.

```
CollectionReference peopleRef = mFirestore.collection("users");
    peopleRef.whereEqualTo("fullName", "John Doe")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```